# How to set the Password Hint when setting Windows Account Password using C#

Tags: c#

I have .NET application, that is intended to set password or change password for existing Windows User Account. I have done the coding to Set/Change password and it works fine. My problem is that , while we Set new password for User Account, we need to create Password Hint, but is there any way to save Password Hint in my C#.NET Application?

Can I make this coding OS independent i.e. work on both Win7 and WinXP?

Comment: have you seen this related post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726858/a-userprincipal-equivalent-to-directoryentry-invoke

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Active Directory attribute editor? You can add attributes to your active directory objects, like Skype Username or Password Hint.

As far as I know, Domain security does not do Password Hints like Windows Workstation does.

There are companies that inject their code into the logon screen executable for Windows, which makes the user able to reset his/her password based on completing a form with questions in.

Your application needs to be certified by Microsoft first before they will let you use the logon screen.

3rd party app :: http://www.specopssoft.com/products/specops-password-reset

Microsoft Forefront Identity Manager :: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621362(v=ws.10).aspx